# What is difference between ≈ and ~?

Tags: notation

I'm reading a quantum mechanics book, and it has the following equation:

$$
\Delta x \approx \frac{\lambda}{\sin\alpha} \sim \frac{h}{mc\sin\alpha}
$$

What is the difference between $\approx$ and $\sim$?

Comment: What's the context? It looks like they're using de Broglie's relation $\lambda=h/p$ and then taking $p=mc$ (which could make sense under the right conditions). That kind of detail is important when interpreting notation in a physics text v. a math text.

Comment: OK. After looking at it for awhile I know what they are doing... $\Delta x \approx \frac{\lambda}{\sin \alpha}$ is referring to the positional uncertainty of a particle measured by a microscope with angular aperture $2\alpha$. However, due to the Crompton effect, the wavelength will increase proportional to $\frac{h}{mc}$ when a photon hits a particle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\approx$ is used as the mathematical "approximately" symbol $-$ this means $ \Delta x $ has approximately the same value as $ \frac {\lambda}{\sin \alpha} $. However, $\sim$ is used a proportionality symbol, so there is some factor tacked onto $\frac{h}{mc\sin \alpha}$, which may be $1000$ or $2$ or something else.